# MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen: force redisplay of controls

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController, with controlStyle set to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen. I want to temporarily pause the video if playing, hide the controls, then later redisplay the controls, and if the video had been in play mode continue playing the video.

So I pause and set the controlStyle to MPMovieControlStyleNone, then later set controlStyle back to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen, and start the video if needed. This works fine, except when I set it back to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen, the controls don't automatically reappear. The user must tap to see them. Is there a way to force the display of the controls?  I've seen one method posted, but it depends on digging through the MPMoviePlayer's subviews, which probably isn't appstore safe.